# Recurrence into explicit formulas

Tags: recurrence-relations

Can anyone point me in the right directions for these recurrence problems?  *I'm having trouble figuring this out for my class*

I have to find the explicit formula for $H(n)$ as a fuction of $n$. *Assume that $n$ is the power of the appropiate integer (when applicable).*

$$H(n) = 2H(n - 1) + 2,$$
where the base case is
$$H(1) = 1.$$

This is what I think is right.  But can it be double checked?

$$
\begin{align}
H(n) &= 2H(n - 1) + 2 \\
&= 2(2H(n-2)+2)+2 \\
&= 2 \cdot 2H(n-2) + 2 \cdot 2 + 2 \\
&= 2 \cdot 2(2H(n - 3) + 2) + 2 \cdot 2 + 2 \\
&=\dots \text{(recurrence)} \\
&= 2^{n - 1}H(1) + 2^{n - 2} + 2^{n - 3} + \dots + 2^2 + 2
\end{align}
$$

Then, because $H(1) = 1$,
$$
H(n) = 2^n - 2
$$

Other recurrences:
$$
T(n) = 3T(n - 1) + 3^n, \text{where the base case is } T(0) = 1
$$
Don't really quite grasp the concept of this yet because I'm new.

Another:
$$
T(n) = T(n/2) + n, \text{where the base case is } T(1) = 1
$$

I'm looking for some really good help on how to approach these problems.  I would like the help from this topic to be able to apply it with other problems that are similar!  Thanks for any input on what you think should happen.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  I am going to edit your post to make the math look nice.  You should check that it still reflects your original intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often, a change of variables makes the recurrence easier to solve.  For the first recurrence,
$$
\begin{cases}
H(n) = 2H(n - 1) + 2, & n > 1 \\
H(1) = 1,
\end{cases}
$$
Let $K(n) = H(n) + 2$, which is equivalent to $H(n) = K(n) - 2$.  What recurrence does $K$ satisfy?
$$
K(n) = H(n) + 2 = \big( 2H(n - 1) + 2 \big) + 2 = 2 \big( K(n) - 2 \big) + 4 = 2K(n)
$$
What is the initial condition for $K$?
$$
K(1) = H(1) + 2 = 3
$$
Putting these together, we have
$$
\begin{cases}
K(n) = 2K(n - 1), & n > 1 \\
K(1) = 3,
\end{cases}
$$
The recurrence gives $K(n) = a \cdot 2^n$ for some $a$, and the initial condition gives
$$
a \cdot 2^1 = 3 \quad \Longrightarrow \quad a = \frac{3}{2} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad K(n) = \frac{3}{2} \cdot 2^n = 3 \cdot 2^{n - 1}
$$
Finally, converting back to the original sequence,
$$
H(n) = \left( 3 \cdot 2^{n-1} \right) - 2 = 3 \cdot 2^{n - 1} - 2
$$

*You ought to check that this formula for $H$ actually works.*

---

For the second recurrence, consider $U(n) = T(n) + a \cdot 3^n$?  What value of $a$ makes the recurrence for $U$ particularly simple?

---

The last recurrence doesn't quite make sense?  How can you expand $T(3)$?